# Exporting and importing signing identity and provisional profiles from one Mac to another

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I had a old MacBook pro where I made two apps and submitted to app store. So basically signing identity is in keychain of that machine. After the Mavericks upgrade, I had to shift from that computer to a new iMac which has Mavericks and Xcode 5.1.

My questions is what is the correct way to import all signing identity from the old one to new one so that I would be able to run my apps as well as submit to app store?

NB: I was using a old iPhone 3 to test my apps which does not support iOS 7 so now I am using a iPhone 5c which has to be used and I added that to "Device" section of Member Center in developer.apple.com. How would I able to add that device to a already existing profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. On your MacBook Pro go to KeyChain Access.
2. Export your Apple Development and Distribution Certificate to desktop.
3. Transfer this certificates on to your new Mac.
4. Sync XCode and you'll get your provisioning and distribution certificates.

EDIT :

There is another way to download your provisioning profile after you insert the .p12 file.

1. Go to XCode - Preferences - Account
2. Click on +
3. Then select Add Apple ID.

Your provisioning profiles will be added to XCode.

1. Just right click on the private key and export it as .p12 file and double click on it on the new mac to insert it.
2. Go to apple developer portal download old provisioning profiles.
3. Double click and install it on new mac.

Comment: Okay @Rushi...shall I just right click on the private key and export it as .p12 file and double click on it on the new mac to insert it. Can I then manually download the provisioning profile and double click on it to insert in on xcode?

Comment: I am asking this cause I have not made change to Team section in the new mac however I have provisioning profile from another account as well.

Comment: No I was asking if I could manually download the provisioning profile and double click on it to insert in xcode as we were doing in the previous versions?

Comment: I am disturbing you again @Rushi...Shall I add the device to existing provisioing profile by right clicking on it and selecting "Add to portal". Will this add to any of the provisioing profile or it will ask me to choose from

Comment: Thats why I am asking you. Actually I made a provisioing profile long ago and it was built manually not by xcode and now I just want a new device and download the same profile to xcode to run my app...whts the procedure. Please help me out

Comment: Then I will first have to delete that profile from member center and regenerate it with all old and new device. Am I right?

Comment: how would I do it? I dont know what is the procedure?

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your time. I will try these steps and get back to you and accept your answer in a while

Comment: Yeah I am working on it....I did export and import the signing identity. Downloaded the provisioning profile however i am not able to make Archieve as the device was not added and I am not seeing a space to add device to provisioning profile however I can add the device to other profiles. Why so?

Comment: I found that clicking "Download all" was an important step, as otherwise my development certificate was left with "Create" button next to it.